# prepareForReuse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Can someone please show me how to use prepareForReuse?  I have been searching for hours and read dev docs.

In my custom cell, which extends UITableViewCell I have the prepareForReuse method and its getting called, but what do I do with it (having rendering issues). Do I do this
deadline = @"" for each label?

```
@implementation PostTableCustomCellController
@synthesize authorName;
@synthesize deadline;
@synthesize distance;
@synthesize interestedCount;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize avatar;
@synthesize viewForBackground;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) prepareForReuse {
    NSLog(@"prep for reuse");
    [self clearFields];
}

- (void) clearFields {

    NSLog(@"clearFields was called Jason");


}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? There's generally no reason to clear out labels in a cell since you'll probably just set the labels to some other text if/when the cell is actually reused.

Comment: You're also forgetting to call super, as instructed by the documentation.

Comment: According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW33), _"For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should always reset all content when reusing a cell."_

So that means, you **should not** reset the text of the label in `prepareForReuse` method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once an object is constructed, calling the any of the `init` methods is unacceptable, so there must be some way to reset the object back to a neutral state before it gets reused. That's what `prepareForReuse` is for. You use that method to put the object back in the same state it was in right after the `init` method was called so that the calling code will do the same thing, whether it is given a new object or a reused one.

Comment: So what would I put in the clearFields function to clear out?  How do I set it back to the state it was after init? SomeUILabel = NO; or someUILabel.text = @"";

Comment: are you doing any custom drawing?  if not, you should be able to just set the text to @"".  It's hard to say without see what is in your cell.

Comment: jgervin, you need to do whatever it takes to set the cell's fields to the same value they were immediately after the init was completed. What that is exactly depends on what you did in the initialization code that you commented out. It may be as simple as calling [self setX: nil] on all your fields, or it may be more complex.

Comment: Don't know why the answer was voted down originally - I found Daniel's answer very clear and to the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In one of my apps I have persistent object instances, one per row, which know about 'their' UITableViewCell instance. (When the row is visible so they actually have one).

In this case, `prepareForReuse` is just an opportunity to tell a row object that its UITableViewCell instance is about to be given away to some other row object, i.e. the original row no longer has a visible presence in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

(A late answer - but for those who stumble across this question)

If you don't want to subclass UITableViewCell and override the `-(void)prepareForReuse` method, you could consider using the `<UITableViewDelegate>` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // prepare cell before it is displayed
}
```

This would allow you to `prepare` the cell prior to it being displayed.

Comment: is the the same as using prepare for reuse method?

Comment: This call occurs *after* the cell has been created, not before.

Comment: @Ken - hopefully we are generally *reusing* cells not *creating* - what we are wanting to do is set up a cell (existing or new) before it is *displayed*

Comment: I believe this answer is good even if, at the time, they didn't know why or when it should be used. It achieves a similar result, and with lazy-loading, sometimes you need it. This just does it in the containing class, prepare in the first-party class (cell itself)